# Mouse Move Effects - Css maybe Javascript maybe flash?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, mousemove

I was on a website the other day, I have looked through my history, twitter everything and cant find the website.

Basically, when I moved my mouse there was a red fluid like velvet effect that followed my mouse and slowly faded.

It was really cool and would love to add it to my website.

I hope I havent explained it too badly.

I was wondering how this would be done, does any one know of anything like this? example links, tutorials, scripts etc. All would be great.

Comment: You can't do "slowly faded" with just css.

Comment: I'm thinking, but I can't think of an easy way to do this in javascript either. :)

Comment: Could you get the effect without fading away?

Comment: I said that you can't do "slowly faded" in css because css doesn't know about time. You can do this with javascript + css, but your 'fluid' requirement is a little difficult. I'm not sure how to do this in a way that would look good. It might be possible with some of the new stuff in HTML 5 - I don't know so much about that.

Comment: You could do something like this with the HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Flash
I've Googled *Liquid Menu* and found some links pointing to a program using Flash to create these buttons. However, it isn't a free program. But with some help, you should be able to make it yourself.
Liquid Menu, by the way, also refers to a menu where the buttons scale according to the page width and the text in the button. So don't be freaked out when a topid or site doesn't relate to your question

Answer (score 0):

I am now trying but you could do that in CSS transformations (for timely things), gradients (you may choose very light yellow and deep red), box shadows (for a folding effect in edges), and blah blah blah.